# Xcode Instruments: Leaks - App crashes on launch

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

Xcode Instruments: Leaks - App crashes on launch

The app crashes on both, a device and in a Simulator.

**What could cause the app to crash with the Instruments attached, while working correctly when installed using the cable or over the air via Fabric.**

Update:
Launching the "Allocations" instrument with the "Leaks" tab helps:
[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually I think this is a bug of Instruments. Try to use the *Allocations* template instead, then click + and add the *Leaks* tool.

Comment: True, it's a bug. Your approach worked well and solved the issue.

Comment: Great @tdimeco this is it.

Comment: @tdimeco Thanks, made my day.

Comment: Still struggling on Xcode 9.3.1, but this workaround is working.

Comment: I'm getting same error and this stoped working for me on Xcode 9.3.1

Comment: I did, also started you. I take care of the people ;)

Comment: This bug still happen on Xcode Version 10.0 beta 6 (10L232m)

Comment: I have just erased all the contents and settings of simulator and boom!

Comment: For me both leaks and allocations are crashing

Comment: mine was not blocking, but it was frozen since the beginning, and this has also resolved it

Comment: With XCode Version 11.0 (11A420a), Allocations template crashed too. Still finding a way out.

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1, the leaks template crashes, but this workaround works fine.

Comment: when using leaks my app kept getting stuck on the splashscreen, when changed to allocations it works perfect, 

Answer (score 11):

I found my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392717/3118542), but only after discovering the "Console" view in Instruments, which included the following log message right after the app appeared to crash:

```
This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0
```

[image]

I used Xcode 10.2.1 and an iPad running iOS 12.4. So to reiterate the answer (credits to user **msk**):

> If iOS >= 12.2, provide `/usr/lib/swift` as a first argument for Runpath Search Paths (under "Linking" in your Build Settings).

Comment: Yes this fixed it for me!  Thank you!