# This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode10.2

The app crashes on launch when running from XCode 10.2 (before and after Swift 5.0 migration) with this on console

> This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to
>   12.2.0.

I understand the error, but not sure what is required to fix this.

Comment: We've seen this as well on some CI jobs running Xcode 10.2.

Comment: You folks are using Buck as well, right? I'm wondering if it's the binary version of `xctest` that we are using. That's my current hypothesis.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure `/usr/lib/swift` is the first argument for runtime search
paths for linker if iOS >= 12.2, it should load platform libraries.

Comment: Did you have to patch Buck itself for that?

Comment: We are not using Buck and still getting this error. I wonder if there is any generic solution for this..

Comment: We have our own fork of BUCK, where we fixed,

Comment: Is this similar to the path you used for Buck? https://gist.github.com/shepting/703b1eda5a4784dfd9ecb4879626bd1f

Comment: @StevenHepting yup

Comment: I've never even heard of BUCK, but this solution worked for me! Thanks, now I can finally proceed with profiling my app.

Answer (score 70):

Go to BuildSettings -> Linking -> runpath search path and add

> /usr/lib/swift

as your 1st argument like this:

[image: Image of dialog]

Comment: I know that it is not allowed to say thank you here but I will write: THANK YOU!

Answer (score 31):

Got it fixed in our ObjectiveC-only project by adding empty Swift file.
 **Don't remove it**, just keep it there forever!

Comment: This is ugly but it works. Did not try adding the swift lib to the runtime search paths, which may have also fixed the issue, and would be more elegant, but its late in the day and im looking for quick wins at this stage.

Comment: Was having the same issue while integrating lottie in react native ios. This answer worked off the bat.

Comment: Mine fixed too, I dont know why?

Answer (score 4):

For anybody not using BUCK but still experiencing this issue, try adding `/usr/lib/swift` in your target's Runtime Search Paths (under Build Settings). Instantly fixed things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Go to "Window" tab -> "Devices and Simulators"
2. Switch to "Simulators" tab
3. Click on "+" in bottom left corner
4. Select "iPhone X" (or whatever device you see in console error) in "Device Type" select
5. Click "Create"

Answer (score 0):

Check that the version of iOS Deployment Target in Build Settings are installed correctly, especially when you use app extensions (todayextension, shareextension) 
all versions must be the same.