# This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0 - react-native-whatsapp-stickers

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10.2

I'm getting this error while installing app to the iPhone 6.
Device runs on iOS 12.2, XCode 10.2, Swift 5.

This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0.
2019-04-07 14:21:17.896723+0530 AvuruduwithNestomalt[254:4489] This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0.
(lldb)

I added empty swift file to the project to fix this issue. but then i'm getting this error.

objc[265]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods

Comment: This might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361057/this-copy-of-libswiftcore-dylib-requires-an-os-version-prior-to-12-2-0